# LINQ - Cannot implicitly convert type with custom data model list property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

Despite dozens of browser tabs open with various LINQ threads, I still cannot seem to get my particular LINQ query to work correctly.

I'm working in an ASP.NET MVC 5 web application and my exact error message is:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 
'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' to 
'System.Collections.Generic.List<TurboApp.Models.Submodel>'
```

In my controller, I'm trying to build a custom data model that I can hand off to a view. The curve ball is that I need to group my data in such a way that I can have a list of part/engine details, with multiple "submodels" of vehicle that the part will fit. The query looks like this:

```cs
var parts = _db.vwFullPartData
.Where(d => d.VehicleMakeID == make &&
    d.VehicleModelID == model &&
    d.VehicleYearID == year)
.Take(20)
.GroupBy(d => new { d.PN, d.Description, d.Cyl, d.Liter, d.Fuel })
.Select(x => new TurboDetailsListViewModel
{
    Pn = x.Key.PN,
    Description = x.Key.Description,
    Cyl = x.Key.Cyl,
    Liter = x.Key.Liter,
    Fuel = x.Key.Fuel,

    Submodels = x.Select(s => s.Submodel).ToList()
});
```

Then I pass `parts` to a view:

```cs
return PartialView("_PartList", parts);
```

It's entirely possible that I have missed something simple in my model. I'm focused on that `Submodel` column in my table and need to build some sort of set of applicable `Submodels`. Currently I'm trying to use a `List` but let me know if there's a better way. Here's my model, called `TurboDetailsListViewModel.cs`

```cs
namespace TurboApp.Models
{
    public class TurboDetailsListViewModel
    {
        public string Pn { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Cyl { get; set; }
        public decimal? Liter { get; set; }
        public string Fuel { get; set; }
        public List<Submodel> Submodels { get; set; }
    }

    public class Submodel
    {
        public string SubmodelName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Maybe one of you pros out there can point me in the right direction! I think I will be OK with building the view once I have the model filled in correctly. I'm planning on using nested Razor `foreach` loops.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: when do you get this error? on a post back?

Comment: @wags also post your partial view

Comment: @DanielA.White I'm seeing the error when I try to build the project. Hamlet Hakobyan's answer below is the direction I needed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Submodels = x.Select(s => new Submodel{SubmodelName = s.Submodel}).ToList()
```

Comment: Thanks for offering this simple fix! Changing that line in my controller made everything build correctly. I seem to have an issue with my view, since I'm trying to make it typed to this custom model. I'll post the code.